# wxpython - panel not clearing when resizing

Tags: python, wxpython

This code successfully draws the SVG onto the screen. However, when I resize the window, the original image stays superimposed over the screen, while it redraws it underneath.

Before Resizing:
[image: Before resizing]

After Maximizing:
[image: After Maximizing]

It's especially noticable if you drag to resize
[image: dragging while resizing]

```
# import igraph  # either uncomment and install igraph or provide output.svg in the same dir
import wx
import wx.svg


class NNGui(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super().__init__(parent, title=title, size=(800, 600))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # main graphics box
        self.screen = MainScreen(self.panel)
        vbox.Add(self.screen, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=10)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.on_resize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MAXIMIZE, self.on_resize)

        # command box
        self.cmd_box = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER | wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
        vbox.Add(self.cmd_box, flag=wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.BOTTOM | wx.EXPAND, border=10)
        self.cmd_box.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.do_char)

        self.panel.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Layout()
        self.Centre()

    def do_char(self, e):
        # handle keypresses
        e.Skip()

    def on_resize(self, e):
        print('resize!')
        # self.screen = MainScreen(self.panel)
        
        self.screen.Refresh()  # thank you Rolf-of-Saxony
        # self.panel.Refresh()
        # self.Refresh()
        
        self.screen.Update()
        # self.panel.Update()
        # self.Update()
        e.Skip()


class MainScreen(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.img = wx.svg.SVGimage.CreateFromFile('output.svg')

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.on_paint)

    def on_paint(self, e):
        print('screen painted!')
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush('black'))
        dc.Clear()

        dc_dim = min(self.Size.width, self.Size.height)
        img_dim = min(self.img.width, self.img.height)
        scale = dc_dim / img_dim
        width = int(self.img.width * scale)
        height = int(self.img.height * scale)

        # ctx = wx.GraphicsContext.Create(dc)
        # self.img.RenderToGC(ctx, scale)

        bmp = self.img.ConvertToBitmap(scale=scale, width=width, height=height)
        px_to_center = int((self.Size.width - width) / 2)
        dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, px_to_center, 0)

        e.Skip()


class NNGraph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.g = igraph.Graph.GRG(50, 0.2)

    def write_svg(self, filename='output.svg'):
        assert filename.endswith('.svg')

        igraph.plot(self.g, filename)


def main():
    # graph = NNGraph()  # either uncomment and install igraph or provide output.svg in the same dir
    # graph.write_svg()
    app = wx.App()
    frame = NNGui(None, title='NeuronicNodes')
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've tried applying Update() to several panels, bound events for EVT_SIZE, EVT_PAINT, tried recreating the panel... I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Try `Refresh` before the `Update` if you want to immediately redraw the window unconditionally.

Comment: That fixed the resizing, but when hitting maximize it still gives issues.

Comment: Solved! using Refresh and not Update fixed it. Thanks!